# Dust.js multi level array data

Tags: javascript, template-engine, dust.js

My JSON data looks something like this:

```
{
    data:[
        [
            {"title": "Text1"},
            {"title": "Text2"},
            {"title": "Text3"}
        ],
        [
            {"title": "Text4"},
            {"title": "Text5"},
            {"title": "Text6"}
        ]
    ]
}
```

I want to use the data to generate a table. So far, I only manage to get it generate rows.

```
{#data}
    <tr>
      <td>{title}</td>
    </tr>
{/data}
```

How can I get it generate columns? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra loop as each value in the first array is also an array:

```
{#data}
    <tr>
        {#.}
            <td>{.title}</td>
        {/.}
    </tr>
{/data}
```